# Error al compilar presentación en Beamer

Tags: latex

estoy tratando de compilar una presentación en beamer y obtengo el siguiente error:

> ! Emergency stop.<> presentacionPHP.tex (job aborted, no legal \end
>   found)Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:22963 strings out of
>   493029434846 string characters out of 6136233766400 words of memory
>   out of 500000025995 multiletter control sequences out of
>   15000+60000030868 words of font info for 41 fonts, out of 8000000 for
>   90001141 hyphenation exceptions out of 819156i,14n,75p,953b,4162s
>   stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s! ==> Fatal
>   error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Tambíen obtengo un warning por lo que creo que el error puede estar en la implementación del paquete listing:

> Package Listings Warning: Text dropped after begin of listing on input
>   line 84.

Adjunto el código fuente (El trozo de código del warning se encuentra al final):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Hannover}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}

%Packages Added
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lmodern}

%Predefined colors.
\definecolor{colorPHP}{HTML}{54769d}
\definecolor{colorBlue}{HTML}{FFFF00}
\definecolor{colorNaranja}{HTML}{7ba1d6}

%\author{Roberto García Antoranz}
\title{PHP}

%Set degraded color on left sidebar.
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas \beamer@sidebarside}%
                  [vertical shading][top=colorPHP,bottom=colorNaranja]
\makeatother

%Set style to lstlisting.
\lstdefinestyle{base}{
  language=PHP,
  emptylines=1,
  breaklines=true,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{black},
  moredelim=**[is][\color{green}]{@}{@},
}

%Set color on the frames, section and blocks.
\setbeamercolor{section in sidebar shaded}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{title in sidebar}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=white, bg=colorPHP}
\setbeamercolor{section in sidebar}{bg=colorBlue,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=red, bg=colorNaranja}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=blue!75!black}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{../../Documentos/phpLogo.png}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Instalar PHP.}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=50} %Beamer Transparent Overlay

\onslide<1-> \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!5,colframe=blue!60!black,title=Linux]
 Dos maneras dependiendo de la distribución:
  \tcblower  
    \color{green}{\$} \color{black}{sudo apt-get install php} \\
    \color{green}{\$} \color{black}{sudo yum install php}
\end{tcolorbox}

\onslide<2-> \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!5,colframe=blue!60!black,title=Windows]
 ...
\end{tcolorbox}

\onslide<3->  \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!5,colframe=blue!60!black,title=Mac]
 Tambíen desde su página web: \\
 \color{red}{https://git-scm.com/download/mac}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Primer Programa en PHP.}
%Trozo Codigo.
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,style=base]
<?php
   echo "Hola Mundo";
?>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Sugerencia metodológica: en casos como este, comenta progresivamente cada `frame` o cada bloque de líneas de código y compila, hasta aislar el error!

Answer (score 1):

Cuando se usa `listings` se debe hacer uso de la opción `fragile` en el `frame`.

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Primer Programa en PHP.}
%Trozo Codigo.
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,style=base]
<?php
   echo "Hola Mundo";
?>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
```

Más información en [Why LaTeX beamer needs fragile when using verbatim](http://pbelmans.ncag.info/blog/2011/02/20/why-latex-beamer-needs-fragile-when-using-verbatim/)

Otra cosa, hay una falta ortográfica en la palabra "también", se colocó la tilde en la `i`.